# Weird solid infill for chamfer

Tags: slicing, infill, prusaslicer

I am very frustrated with some weird solid infill issue, mostly due to sloped wall such as chamfer for fillet.

Here is an example. I have a 20x20x20 mm cube with 2 mm rounded chamfer at the bottom shown in the figure.

[image]

When I slice it using default 0.20 mm profile, at layer 5 I can see some wiggle solid infill near the wall, shown in figure:

[image]

I thought that is to help create the chamfer. BUT, if I increase the bottom solid layer number to 50, at layer 51 (which is way above the chamfer region already), I start to see that same wiggle solid infill again! This can't be correct... Shown in the figure:

[image]

I am using the most recent PrusaSlicer 2.2.0

The reason I want to get rid of those wiggles is because they create crazy vibrations which then create layer shift for me...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What software did you create the cube in? Also, please post the setting for slicing (most relevant); it appears that there is a solid infill layer at layer 50? Looks as if 2 cubes are stacked...

Comment: Stiffen your frame. That should be your foremost concern. Just throwing that in here.

Comment: user77232, the wiggles of note are not structurally related, they are coded into the build by the slicer.

Comment: What are your wall settings -- thickness, etc.

Comment: Please answer in which software the cube is designed.